# how do I avoid avoid multiple round trips for queries with MySQLdb with python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am reading in some raw files and inserting them into a DB. This will involve MILLIONS of records, and for each record, I have multiple inserts (many tables). When I was testing locally, it was going quickly, but for the whole dataset, I need to work with a remote database. It is painfully slow this way, which I assume is because of all the trips over the network to delete/insert.

I am using the MySQLdb module (python) and at the moment, I have things such as the following:

```
# setup connection
con = mdb.connect('remote.host', 'database_user', '123456789', 'database_name');

... read files, loop through records, etc...

# clear out data related to current record
cur.execute("DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = %s", article.id)
cur.execute("DELETE FROM authors WHERE article_id = %s", article.id)
cur.execute("DELETE FROM addresses WHERE article_id = %s", article.id)
cur.execute("DELETE FROM citation_references WHERE article_id = %s", article.id)
cur.execute("DELETE FROM citation_patents WHERE article_id = %s", article.id)

# insert the article
cur.execute("INSERT INTO articles (article_id, doctype, keywords, language, title) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" , (article.id, article.doctype, ';'.join(article.keywords), article.language, article.title))

# insert all the authors
for au in article.authors:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO isi_authors (article_id, name_first, name_last, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (article.id, au.first_name, au.last_name, au.email))

... other loops like the authors to insert 10-20 citations per article, multiple addresses, etc ...
```

From what I can tell, MySQLdb does not allow me to send multiple queries at once. There must be a way for me to avoid the network delays. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like simply using foreign key relationships correctly and cascading the delete would fix some of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `executemany`. Here's an example from the [manual](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

```
c.executemany(
      """INSERT INTO breakfast (name, spam, eggs, sausage, price)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
      [
      ("Spam and Sausage Lover's Plate", 5, 1, 8, 7.95 ),
      ("Not So Much Spam Plate", 3, 2, 0, 3.95 ),
      ("Don't Wany ANY SPAM! Plate", 0, 4, 3, 5.95 )
      ] )
```

In your case it would look something like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO isi_authors (article_id, name_first, name_last, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
params = [(article.id, au.first_name, au.last_name, au.email) for au in article.authors]
cur.executemany(sql, params)
```

From the documentation of `executemany`:

> This method improves performance on multiple-row INSERT and
>   REPLACE. Otherwise it is equivalent to looping over args with
>   execute().

Comment: I was under the impression executemany still did multiple roudtrips. Am I wrong?

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: According to the code documentation it "improves performance on multiple-row INSERT and REPLACE". See my update.

Comment: great. Thanks. I totally missed that. What would you suggest for the multiple deletes? Setting up cascades as suggested by Endophage in the comment to the original post?

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: Sometimes cascading deletes make sense, in which case using them would improve performance. Other times though you might not want your deletes to cascade to avoid accidental data loss, in which case you should stick with your current approach. I assume the vast majority of the time taken is due to the inefficient insert loops and not the deletes anyway.

Answer (score 4):

At least `MySQLdb` 1.2.3 seems to allow multiple queries out of the box, you just have to call `cursor.nextset()` to cycle through the returned result sets.

```
db = conn.cursor()
db.execute('SELECT 1; SELECT 2;')

more = True
while more:
    print db.fetchall()
    more = db.nextset()
```

If you want to be absolutely sure the support for this is enabled, and/or disable the support, you can use something like this:

```
MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON = 0
MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF = 1

conn.set_server_option(MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON)
# Multiple statement execution here...
conn.set_server_option(MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF)
```

If there's an error while executing one of the queries, mysql won't execute any queries after that point. The `db.execute()` call will throw the exception if it originated from the first query, otherwise the appropriate `db.nextset()` will do it, so you can fetch the result sets from the successfull queries before getting the exception.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sweet, I really needed this

Answer (score 1):

mySQL INSERT syntax does allow it. Compare 1) and 2)

```
1. INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3);
2. INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

In the second case you're inserting three rows at once.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Hopefully it will give you ideas.

PS: this is language-independent way

Comment: This was such an obvious idea! I can't believe I hadn't thought of it. Thanks.